# How to check record existance in Rxjava2?

Tags: spring-boot, rx-java2, reactive

I have implementation with reactive programming and I'm using Springboot Framework, Rxjava2, reactive spring data framework. I have a scenario about saving record into mongodb when the record is not exist.

But when I check with the record reactively, I found the emitter stopped to proceed.

Below is my sample code. I have 4 datas and 2 of that were not in database. I found emitter proceed with the data which exists in database only.

```
val movies = mutableListOf("Secret Mother (Mainland) - 秘密媽媽","Life For Life - 命情真","Before Dawn - 愛在暴風的日子","The Threat Of Love 2 - Loving ou 我愛你2")

        Observable
            .fromIterable(movies)
            .flatMapMaybe {
                videoInfoService
                    .findVideoByTitle(it)
                    .switchIfEmpty(Maybe.empty())
            }
            .subscribe(object: Observer<VideoInfo>{
                override fun onComplete() {
                    println("on complete ")
                }

                override fun onSubscribe(d: Disposable) {
                    println("on subscribe ")
                }

                override fun onNext(t: VideoInfo) {
                    println("on next: ${t.title}")
                }

                override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }

            })
```

Appreciate your guidance. I know Rxjava2 not able to proceed with null value from other post I wrote this morning, I guess it should be some way to handle this scenario.

Thanks,

Comment: what's the signature of your method to save the record in your mongodb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming that your method to save the record in mongodb returns a Completable:

```
fun store(movie: Movie): Completable
```

and your `videoInfoService.findVideoByTitle` method returns a `Movie` instance, you can change your code to:

```
    Observable
        .fromIterable(movies)
        .flatMapSingle { title ->
            videoInfoService
                .findVideoByTitle(title)
                .switchIfEmpty {
                    Single.defer {
                        val movie = Movie(title)
                        store(movie)
                            .andThen(Single.just(movie))
                    }
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the output I want.

Thanks @Gustavo provide the answer and I got the hint from @Gustavo's answer to come out this answer.

```
val movies = mutableListOf("Secret Mother (Mainland) - 秘密媽媽","Life For Life - 命情真","Before Dawn - 愛在暴風的日子","The Threat Of Love 2 - Loving ou 我愛你2")

        Observable
            .fromIterable(movies)
            .flatMap {
                videoInfoService
                    .findVideoByTitle(it)
                    .toObservable()
                    .switchIfEmpty{
                        // Save the video
                        save(it)
                    }
            }
            .subscribe(object: Observer<VideoInfo>{
                override fun onComplete() {
                    println("on complete ")
                }

                override fun onSubscribe(d: Disposable) {
                    println("on subscribe ")
                }

                override fun onNext(t: VideoInfo) {
                    println("on next: ${t.title}")
                }

                override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }

            })
```